# Get random text between two regexen

Tags: regex, bash, random

I have a file of scraped posts that looks like this:

```
1 Name: foo

Hello, my name is foo.

2 Name: bar

Hello.
Multi
line
post.

3 Name: foo

Hello, bar!
```

I am capable of writing a regex that will match just the headers (because they have some HTML that's not allowed in posts).

How would I get a random post from this file? Just the text, no names or such.

EDIT: Note that some post numbers may be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -0777 -ne 'a=$_.split(/\d+\sName:.*/);puts a.reject(&:empty?).shuffle.first' file


Hello, my name is foo.

$ ruby -0777 -ne 'a=$_.split(/\d+\sName:.*/);puts a.reject(&:empty?).shuffle.first' file


Hello, bar!
```

Comment: My god, it's almost like Perl. <3